SCIM for custom app using Google as an IdP
I'm building an app where we'll be implementing SCIM 2.0 for User Auto-Provisioning. This is to get users created in my DB by integrating with various IdPs as per the requirements. I want to clearly highlight here that my need is just User-Provisioning and not SSO as I have my own password-less login in place.
I want to start off with Google but when I read the Google's documentation I'm unable to find SCIM support for custom apps. I've gone through QnA(s) on various forums and what I understand is to make my app support SCIM with Google as an IdP is to get my app listed in Google's catalogue of apps, but that will need me to implement SSO(using SAML) as well which I don't want.
Can someone help me understand-
How can I achieve this?
If I go on implementing SSO just for the sake of getting my app approved by Google for SSO + User Provisioning(SCIM), will there be any workaround to skip the SSO part during configuration?(I've seen something relatable in Keeper's doc for SCIM implementation) Refer image attached
Is my understanding about the entire thing with Google correct?enter image description here
